# Why I cannot call func in another python file?

Tags: python

I make 2 python files: `MineSweeping.py` and `CmdColor.py`
And in  `MineSweeping.py` I want to call a func defined in `CmdColor.py` to make the shell with color output, but failed.

The code of `CmdColor.py` is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
#encoding: utf-8  
import ctypes  

STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10  
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE= -11
STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12  

FOREGROUND_BLACK = 0x0  
FOREGROUND_BLUE = 0x01 # text color contains blue.  
FOREGROUND_GREEN= 0x02 # text color contains green.  
FOREGROUND_RED = 0x04 # text color contains red.  
FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x08 # text color is intensified.  

BACKGROUND_BLUE = 0x10 # background color contains blue.  
BACKGROUND_GREEN= 0x20 # background color contains green.  
BACKGROUND_RED = 0x40 # background color contains red.  
BACKGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x80 # background color is intensified.  

class Color:  

    std_out_handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)  

    def set_cmd_color(self, color, handle=std_out_handle):  
        """(color) -> bit 
        Example: set_cmd_color(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY) 
        """  
        bool = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, color)  
        return bool  

    def reset_color(self):  
        self.set_cmd_color(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE)  

    def print_red_text(self, print_text):  
        self.set_cmd_color(FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY)  
        print print_text  
        self.reset_color()  



if __name__ == "__main__":  
    clr = Color()
    clr.print_red_text('red')  
    clr.print_green_text('green')  
    clr.print_blue_text('blue')  
    clr.print_red_text_with_blue_bg('background')
```

And in  `MineSweeping.py` I do so to call the func:

```
import CmdColor
...    
    clr = CmdColor.Color()
    clr.print_red_text('red')
```

But the output string 'red' is white

If I merge the `CmdColor.py` into `abc.py`, then it can output a red string of 'red'.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/tomxuetoy/Python_MineSweeping

Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure nothing in the `...` is relevant? (Perhaps you could make it a three line minimal example?)

Comment: @David Robinson Please check my updated post, the code's link is provided. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you might try the colorama module in PyPI instead of using Win32 invasiveness... :)

Comment: Hmm, your code works well for me...